# Tensorflow CNN test data splitting and array sizing problems

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I've tried to figure things out myself and not fallback to actually creating an account here but as a self-taught beginner I've reached a wall with this code.

I'm having two major issues besides optimizing the net architecture when everything is working:

- Everytime I've tried to create a new dataset for a test batch I've ran into 'xTensor is not a Tensor' error and could run a session through it, unlike with the iterator which works just fine. I'm loading custom data with dir names as labels with no manually created train and test directories. I'm probably missing a proper method for tf.
- I can't work around the current first error I get which is:
  'ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (100,) for Tensor 'Placeholder_1:0', which has shape '(?, 1)' while feed_dict {y=batch_y}. I've tried some of solutions posted on SO but couldn't get it to work.

I'm pasting the whole thing, ########### are the problem triggering zones at the very bottom in the session.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import os

# load custom imageset directory
data_path = r"..\datasets\images\flowers"

# setup hypervariables for labels and images format
n_classes = 5
img_width = 64
img_length = 64
channels = 3

# setup hypervariables for network
learning_rate = 0.0001
epochs = 2
batch_size = 100
drop_rate = 0.6

imagepaths = list()
labels = list()
label = 0
classes = sorted(os.walk(data_path).__next__()[1])
# List each sub-directory (the classes)
for c in classes:
    c_dir = os.path.join(data_path, c)
    walk = os.walk(c_dir).__next__()

    # Add each image to the training set
    for sample in walk[2]:
        imagepaths.append(os.path.join(c_dir, sample))
        labels.append(label)
    label += 1

total_input = len(labels)
# Convert to Tensor
imagepaths = tf.convert_to_tensor(imagepaths, dtype=tf.string)
labels = tf.convert_to_tensor(labels, dtype=tf.int32)
# Build a TF Queue, shuffle data
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((imagepaths, labels))

# read, decode, resize and normalize images on RGB range
def parse(imagepath, label):
    image = tf.read_file(imagepath)
    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image, channels=channels)
    image = tf.image.resize_images(image, [img_length, img_width])
    image = image * 1.0/255
    return image, label

dataset = dataset.map(parse)
dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=batch_size*10)
dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
next_batch = iterator.get_next()

# hypervariables for layers' output size
K = 16
L = 32
M = 200

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 4326])
x_shaped = tf.reshape(x, [-1, img_length, img_width, 3])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1])

# weight, bias with stride size and activation method after convolution for layer 1
W1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([5, 5, 3, K], stddev=0.03))
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([K], stddev=0.01))
stride = 1
y1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.conv2d(x_shaped, W1, strides=[1, stride, stride, 1], padding='SAME') + b1)

# weight, bias with stride size and activation method after convolution for layer 2
W2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([5, 5, K, L], stddev=0.03))
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([L], stddev=0.01))
stride = 2  # output is 14x14
y2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.conv2d(y1, W2, strides=[1, stride, stride, 1], padding='SAME') + b2)

yflat = tf.reshape(y2, [-1, 7 * 7 * L])

W3 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([7 * 7 * L, M], stddev=0.1))
b3 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([M], stddev=0.01))
y3 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(yflat, W3) + b3)

W4 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([M, 10], stddev=0.1))
b4 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([10], stddev=0.01))
ylogits = tf.matmul(y3, W4) + b4
y_ = tf.nn.softmax(ylogits)

# add cross entropy for back prop
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(logits=ylogits, labels=y_))

# add an optimiser for back prop
optimiser = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cross_entropy)

# define an accuracy assessment operation
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

with tf.Session() as sess:

    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    ########## temporary solution for test_x, test_y
    test_x, test_y = sess.run(next_batch)
    total_batch = int(total_input / batch_size)
    # define the iterator for the network
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        avg_cost = 0
        for i in range(total_batch):
            batch_x, batch_y = sess.run(next_batch)
            ########## ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (100,) for Tensor 'Placeholder_1:0' -> y: batch_y
            _, c = sess.run([optimiser, cross_entropy], feed_dict={x_shaped: batch_x, y: batch_y}) 
            avg_cost += c / total_batch

        test_acc = sess.run(accuracy,feed_dict={x: test_x, y: test_y})
        print("Epoch:", (epoch + 1), "cost =", "{:.3f}".format(avg_cost), " test accuracy: {:.3f}".format(test_acc))
        summary = sess.run(merged, feed_dict={x: test_x, y: test_y})

    print("\nTraining complete!")
    print(sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: test_x, y: test_y}))
```

Answer (score 0):

are you sure that this part:

```
_, c = sess.run([optimiser, cross_entropy], feed_dict={x_shaped: batch_x, y: batch_y})
```

doesn't have to be:

```
_, c = sess.run([optimiser, cross_entropy], feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y})
```

furthermore you've a batchsize of 100, the data is right of the array, the shape is not complete.
What you have (dummy example)

```
np.zeros((100,)).shape
>>> (100,)
```

here 100 matches the '?' of the required shape: shape '(?, 1)', the one can be easily added, and it often occurs that numpy does not do this. See the following code:

```
 np.expand_dims(np.zeros((100,)), axis=-1).shape
 >>> (100, 1)
```

axis -1 stand for the last axis, you basically tell numpy to add a dimension in the end. This does not affect the data itself, but the shape of the array. So your code should be:

```
_, c = sess.run([optimiser, cross_entropy], feed_dict={x_shaped: batch_x, y:np.expand_dims(batch_y, axis=-1)})
```

Comment: First of all thanks for the reply, I wasn't sure I'm not an asshole by simply pasting my stuff and hoping someone will go through all of it and help. 

I'm not sure about swapping 'x' with 'x_shaped', I purposely switched them since the shapes were giving off an error: 

Cannot feed value of shape (100, 64, 64, 3) for Tensor 'Placeholder:0', which has shape '(?, 4326)'

and decided to react as I go through the rest of the network. 

I get what is going on and that I'm missing,I have also found a neat solution on SO: numpy.swapaxes 

Again, thanks for the response.

Comment: well then the placeholder should have shape (None, 64, 64, 3) instead of (None, 4326) which would mean that you can get rid of that x_shaped. I'm not sure how you fixed the error with np.swapaxes, since that does sort of change the data. It might be dangerous to execute, unless you know for sure that it is what you want

Comment: Thank you, sat to it today and it worked as it should. I've had this solution looked up but now it's obvious I couldn't apply it properly. With this out of the way I can now post snippets of code with more concise problems instead of pasting the whole thing.

Comment: I personally don't mind full code snippets if the code is this small, it enables others to see problems you might have not considered before :). If you've any questions feel free to tag me in them, glad to help!

Comment: @t-kehler I'm probably messing something up with tagging you in a new question so I'm commenting on the old one. If you could look into my new problem about AttributeError I would be very thankful.